# node.js i have the program but how to run

Tags: node.js

have a program written in node.js  called app.

am having trouble to run.
i put the folder where the program resides, then 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
I put node app.js but i get message
'cannot find module'

what step did i miss? i tried command with c or d drives but it does not find.
in the code is there any place that will have under which drive or folder to run node.js?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{7af60b71-2837-4459-9910-95739900e20d}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectHome />
    <ProjectView>ProjectFiles</ProjectView>
    <StartupFile>app.js</StartupFile>
    <WorkingDirectory>.</WorkingDirectory>
    <OutputPath>.</OutputPath>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AF33F2E-1136-4D97-BBB7-1795711AC8B8};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{9092AA53-FB77-4645-B42D-1CCCA6BD08BD}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="package.json" />
    <Compile Include="app.js" />
    <Compile Include="routes\tasks.js" />
    <Content Include="views\editTask.ejs" />
    <Content Include="views\footer.ejs" />
    <Content Include="views\newTask.ejs" />
    <Content Include="views\taskList.ejs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="routes" />
    <Folder Include="views" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\Node.js Tools\Microsoft.NodejsTools.targets" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>0</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:48022/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>True</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>http://localhost:1337</CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
```

Comment: The most basic practice is to call "node yourMainFile.js". Ultimately, that's what every technique is doing - though you'll eventually find it better to utilize npm and grunt or gulp.

Comment: Are you trying to run your node app from Visual Studio?  Or from a command line prompt?  Is node.exe in your path?  Is app.js in the current directory when you run "node app.js"?

Comment: command prompt  line.

Comment: What about the other questions I asked in my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a command line, where you are in the project's root directory (wherever the file `app.js` is):

```
npm install
node app.js
```

A missing module probably means you need to run that install step. I believe that you can also install modules by right-clicking on the project in Visual Studio's *Solution Explorer*.

Comment: when you run these from which directory and folder? from where the code sits?

Comment: @user3167167, yes, from the root directory of you application.

Comment: Editing for clarification.